# How to show status based on how many times a word appears in a range?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a column with different words and I want to give a status based on how many words there are in that range.

Here is an example:

Column B contains four rows with a rolling curtain, which gives three different  choices: apples, bananas and orange. Now I want to give a status based on how many times a banana is selected. For an example if `banana is selected >=2` and `orange=1` and `apple=1`, the status will be *green*.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Try the countif function. Google: excel countif

Comment: Thanks, I tried but the problem is that I'm making first a calculation how many times "apples" appers and at the same time in that function i'm trying to may a condition based on that first calculation,,

Comment: Like this in cell B4,, Countif("B5:B10, "apples") which may give a value of 4 . But in that countif function I would like to give a condition >2 "True","False" .. Sorry having a problem explaining my self.

Comment: You could nest the countif function in an if statement. Something like `=IF(COUNTIF("B5:B10, "apples")>2,"True","False")`

Comment: Thanks alot, that helped! Now just trying to figure out how I could set up three different status ("True","False", "Inbetween") based on that criteria..

Comment: @Martinswe You can use nested `IF` functions to get the same logic as an ELSE IF. Just put another IF statement  into the "Value if False" area.

Comment: Ok, perfect. Appreciate all your help!

Comment: @MarcoVos You 'could" do a nested IF, but you wouldn't know the results by word - and this may be significant. Martinswe Please define the count outcomes for the other alternatives. It is very easy to build.

Comment: This is how my formula looks right now, it has to be corrected though,,  =IF(COUNTIF(B5:B10;"Apple")>=6;"GREEN";IF((COUNTIF(B5:B10;"Orange"))>2;"YELLOW";IF(COUNTIF(B5:B10;"Banana")>1;"Blue")))

Comment: So there could many different outcomes based on selection between these fruits combination. But my set up is to have status Green if it appears more than or equal to 6 and so on. There will be max 6 of any fruit.

Comment: That’s okay. It’s just a simple matter of editing the IF statement to reflect your “definition”. And remember, you only need one IF statement. OTOH, the COUNTIF still evaluates only three words, but the range needs to cover the relevant number of rows of data in Column B.

Answer (score 0):

The solution requires a combination of "COUNTIF" to count the frequency of words, and an "IF" statement to evaluation the count results and determine the status.

[image]

This screenshot shows how my data is laid out.

Column B contains four cells, each containing the word "banana" or "apple" or "orange".
Column E, rows 1, 2 and 3, contain a COUNTIF statement to count the frequency of the words displayed in Column B.
Column D contains "criteria" to be evaluated

**COUNTIF**
The formula in cell E2 is:

```
= COUNTIF($B$2:$B$5,D2)
```

This translates as 'count all the words in Column B (rows 2 to 5 inclusive) that are equal to the criterion in cell D2 ("apple"). Since "apple" appears only once in Column B, the count is evaluated as = 1.
Note that the range to be evaluated ($B$2:$B$5) is written in absolute format (note the $ signs); this means that the formula can simply be copied down from E2 into E3 and E4.

**IF**
Cell E5 contains an IF statement to determine the status.

```
=IF(AND(E2=1,E3=2,E4=1),"Green", "Not Green")
```

This translates as 'if E2=1 (i.e. "apple"=1) AND E3=2 (i.e. "banana" = 2) AND E3 = 1 (i.e. "orange" = 1), then the status is Green. If not, the status is something else. The OP can created a nested IF in order to satisfy other status outcomes.

**Conditional Formatting**
I used conditional formatting to colour cell E5, include a border and bold the result.

**Exception to OP**
The OP suggests that "banana" can be evaluated as >=2. However since there are only four data cells and "apple" and "orange" must equal 1, the only valid result for a status of "Green" is if "banana" = 2 (rather than >=2).

---

**UPDATE**

[image]

Here's an example of the IF statement to address three possible outcomes:

```
=IF(AND(E16=1,E17=2,E18=1),"Green", IF(AND(E16=1,E17=1,E18=2),"Red","Blue"))
```